# Нужно получить все подрубрики и посты у тех подрубрик | Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

У меня есть три Основных рубрик: az, ru, en (с ярлыками: "page_az", "page_ru", "page_en" соответственно) и соответственно три страницы, с разными языками (az, ru en).
Нужно отдельно получить подрубрики и посты из той же подрубрики.

Например на странице "az" мы должны получить подрубрики и посты из главной рубрики "az", на странице "ru" получить подрубрики и посты из главной рубрики "ru" и аналогично с "en"

Comment: Какое-то изобретение велосипеда, вместо использования стандартных плагинов мультиязычности вроде Polylang или WPML.

Comment: "Получить посты" (и не только посты) - WP_Query. Только так делать многоязычность - это как утолять жажду китайскими палочками. Выше см правильные инструменты.